# How to respond to a basic POST command in PHP

Tags: php, post, http-post

As a new PHP user I have a simple question. I have a client that calls a PHP file on a server that is not embedded in any webpage. The client connects and sends a POST to the server. How do I send bytes back to the client in response to their POST command?

Let me clarify.  We are receiving a POST command from a client.  PHP apparently opens a socket to receive this POST where we can access the contents of the POST command using the following line of code for example:
$postString = file_get_contents("php://input");
Now we want to use the same socket that is open to send a string back to the client, but I don't know how to obtain the socket PHP opened to receive the POST command.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to send anything back from PHP as the response to a request, you can simply output it using `echo`

For example:

```
<?php
echo "test";
?>
```